# PolicyKit vs polkit

Tags: linux, security

What is the difference between [PolicyKit](http://hal.freedesktop.org/docs/PolicyKit/) and [polkit](http://hal.freedesktop.org/docs/polkit/)?  They seem to do the same thing in different ways and seem to be referred to interchangeably, but also seem to be two different things.  Which one is preferred?  Which one should I use?  Why are both packages available in an Ubuntu 10.04 system?

I do know that the configuration files are different, but seem to serve about the same purpose with different syntax: PolicyKit seems to use /etc/PolicyKit/PolicyKit.conf with an XML syntax and polkit seems to use many files in /etc/polkit-1/ with an INI-style syntax.

A note to freedesktop.org: It has taken me the better part of a day to understand what I know now, but I'm still confused.  The documentation for each of PolicyKit and polkit seem to be good, but conflicting information is a great way to turn people off of new technology.

Comment: Read [The Cathedral and the Bazaar](http://catb.org/~esr/writings/homesteading/) to understand there are lots of forks and such in the FOSS world.

Comment: I've actually been to a talk by Eric Raymond, author of The Cathedral and the Bazaar.  I understand the concept of forking software, but if one of these is a fork of another then it would be nice if it were documented somewhere.  I'm also not accustomed to forks of software packages being hosted by the same organization without saying something like "we recommend this new version instead", as is the case with PolicyKit and polkit.

Answer (score 0):

If my memory serves, PolicyKit was renamed to polkit at some point.